# Focus First Invalid Input

Tags: angular, typescript

I've requirement need to focus on the first invalid input of a form after click button. I need to trigger with button submit outside the `<form>`. How to trigger it?. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1xeqy6?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<form focusInvalidInput [formGroup]="form">
  <label for="first">First Name</label>
  <input formControlName="first" />

  <label for="last">Last Name</label>
  <input formControlName="last" />

  <br />
 
</form>

<button (click)="submit()">submit</button>
```

**Component**

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      first: ['', Validators.required],
      last: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log(this.form);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [exportAs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#exportAs) you can expose public method to your template

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focusInvalidInput]',
  exportAs: 'focusInvalidInput'
})
export class FormAutoFocus {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  public focus():void{
    const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');
    console.log("test", invalidControl);
    if (invalidControl) {
      invalidControl.focus();
      console.log("test");
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can access FormAutoFocus instance anywhere in our template

```
<form focusInvalidInput #focusInput="focusInvalidInput" [formGroup]="form">
  <label for="first">First Name</label>
  <input formControlName="first" />

  <label for="last">Last Name</label>
  <input formControlName="last" />
  <br />
</form>

<button (click)="submit();focusInput.focus()">submit</button>
```

[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tt7k5g?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
  <form focusInvalidInput #focusInput="focusInvalidInput" [formGroup]="form">
     <label for="first">First Name</label>
     <input formControlName="first" id="first" />

     <label for="last">Last Name</label>
     <input formControlName="last" id="last" />

     <br />
  </form>
  <button type="submit" (click)="submit();focusInput.onFormSubmit()">
      submit
  </button>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      first: ['', Validators.required],
      last: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      console.log(this.form);
    }
  }
}
```

Then create a directive in the relevant component

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[focusInvalidInput]',
      exportAs:'focusInvalidInput '
    })
    export class FormDirective {
      constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
    
      @HostListener('submit')
      onFormSubmit() {
        const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.ng-invalid');
    
        if (invalidControl) {
          invalidControl.focus();  
        }
      }
    
    }
```

**CSS**

```
input.ng-invalid:focus {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

for more reference  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrnhxg?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to put submit button outside the `<form>`